# Django query phone numbers excluding brackets

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a django query that filters phone numbers (`CharField`) but excludes brackets

eg.

if I search for `0123456789` it would find `(01) 234 567 89`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never like to answer my own questions, but this solution might be helpful to others doing a similar thing:

I defined a function on the model using the `@property` decorator.

```
class MyModel(models.model):
    ....
    phoneNumber = CharField...

    @property
    def raw_phone_number(self):
        # function strips those characters and returns just the number
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can either use [regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex), or you can reformat your search:

```
pn = '0123456789'
Model.objects.filter(phone='(%s) %s %s %s' % (pn[:2], pn[2:5], pn[5:8], pn[8:]))
```

Ideally you normalize all phone numbers and you'd search for them in that format. If you check out `django.contrib.localflavors.us`'s `PhoneNumberField`, it forces all new phone numbers to be saved in `XXX-XXX-XXXX` format, for instance. If you aren't normalizing the phone numbers somehow, you should be. Dealing with multiple potential formats would not be fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions in your lookup. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#s-regex